# Center an img in a navbar, 2 navigation buttons on each side (left and right)

Tags: html, css, navigation, header, navbar

So I'm trying to make a navigation bar (or header?) similar to what I've seen online from another website.

[how i wanted it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRN5V.png)

I've successfully made the logo image centered. But I'm having trouble styling the buttons (like About, Blog, etc.), whether should I use floats or another type of style?

Here's my code to make the image centered:

```css
.nav {
                z-index: 99;
                display: table;
                height: 100px;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: #fdf4e4;
            }
            .nav .logo {
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                display: table-cell;
                vertical-align: middle;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #home_btn {
                margin: 0;
                width: 85px; height: 85px;
                background-image: url(drone.png);
                background-size: cover;
                background-color: black;
                border: transparent;
            }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="logo"><button id="home_btn"></button></div>
</div>
```

But once I insert the text, the image is no longer centered.

```css
.nav {
                z-index: 99;
                display: table;
                height: 100px;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: #fdf4e4;
            }
            .nav .logo {
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                display: table-cell;
                vertical-align: middle;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #home_btn {
                margin: 0;
                width: 85px; height: 85px;
                background-size: cover;
                background-color: black;
                border: transparent;
            }
            .navbar {
                display: table-cell;
                vertical-align: middle;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .navbar .about, .services, .help, .partner {
                font-family: 'Sifonn Pro';
                background-color: transparent;
                border: transparent;
                cursor: pointer;
                font-size: 20px;
                padding: 0 16px;
                color: #061925;
                text-align: center;
            }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
            <div class="logo"><button id="home_btn"></button></div>
            <div class="navbar">
                <button class="about" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='.html'">About Us</button>
                <button class="services" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='.html'">Services</button>
                <button class="help" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='.html'">Help Centre</button>
                <button class="partner" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='.html'">Be Our Partner</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want my 'About Us' and 'Services' to be on the left side of the navbar, while the 'Help Centre' and 'Be Our Partner' to be on the right side. Does anyone know how to do it? With floats or anything is fine, as long as I could get it similar to the sample I got from another website online.

Comment: either with the sue of flex-box or CSS-Grid. Dont use tables unless you want to use it for dispalyign data.

Answer (score 0):

create a 3 column grid with `grid-template-columns: auto min-content auto;` that way, the logo will be centered and only use as much space as needed. the left and right sided columns will take the remaining space equally.

```css
nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto min-content auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

nav div:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: left;
}

nav div:nth-child(1) a {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

nav div:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: right;
}

nav div:nth-child(3) a {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.logo {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>
    <a href="">About Wolfin</a>
    <a href="">Blog</a>
    <a href="">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="logo"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="">Collection</a>
    <a href="">Stories</a>
    <a href="">Shops</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```